# Can't generate Google Analytics DataChart client side with Service Account Token (Invalid Credentials Error)

Tags: javascript, c#, google-analytics, google-analytics-api, google-analytics-firebase

I'm trying to implement **Google Analytics Graphs** via their Javascript API, as the example on their site [link](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/embed-api/server-side-authorization/).

But I keep getting ***"401 Invalid Credentials"*** each time I try to execute *gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart*

I'm getting the access token server side (C#) using the following code with data from the JSON generated for the Service Account

```
var cred = new ServiceAccountCredential(
    new ServiceAccountCredential.Initializer(clientId)
    {
        Scopes = new[] { AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly },
        User = clientEmail,
        ProjectId = "projectID"
    }.FromPrivateKey(privateKey));

var token = cred.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync(authURI);
token.Wait();
var result = token.Result;
return result;
```

or (using the full json string, see Note too)

```
GoogleCredential cred;

var gCred = GoogleCredential.FromJson(json).UnderlyingCredential as
    ServiceAccountCredential;

var token = gCred.GetAccessTokenForRequestAsync("https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth");
return token.Result;
```

While on the **client side**

```
gapi.analytics.auth.authorize({
    'serverAuth': {
      'access_token': '{{ ACCESS_TOKEN_FROM_SERVICE_ACCOUNT }}'
    }
  });
```

goes through and using **gapi.analytics.auth.isAuthorized()** returns true using any of the server side functions but it fails when trying to call

```
  var dataChart1 = new gapi.analytics.googleCharts.DataChart(queryJson);
  dataChart1.execute();
```

returns 401 "Invalid Credentials", the server side query returns values just fine so I think the user permissions is not the issue

NOTE: Using the same code as the second one (generating the credential using the json string without casting as a ServiceAccountCredential) I can get data from the API server side

```
cred = gCred.CreateScoped(scopes);

using (var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer
    {
        HttpClientInitializer = cred
    }))
...
var getReportsRequest = new GetReportsRequest
{
    ReportRequests = new List<ReportRequest> { reportRequest }
};
var batchRequest = reportingService.Reports.BatchGet(getReportsRequest);

var response = batchRequest.Execute(); //This returns a response object with all the data I need
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone has the same issue:

You need to use ***GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault()*** to create the Credential object, in the case of Analytics you should get something like this

```
var credential = GoogleCredential.GetApplicationDefault().CreateScoped(AnalyticsReportingService.Scope.AnalyticsReadonly);
```

This will get the json file from the **Environment Variables** on Windows, so you need to set **GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS** with the path to the json as a System Variable.

Initialize the service and set the service variable

```
using (var reportingService = new AnalyticsReportingService(new BaseClientService.Initializer { HttpClientInitializer = credential }))
{
  var serviceCredential = cred.UnderlyingCredential as ServiceAccountCredential;
}
```